# Ruby Instance Vars from external file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have lots of repeating flash notices all around my rails 3 app and end up typing the same strings every again and again. As well as that I want to remove long strings for flash notices outside of the controllers.

I tried putting them in an external file but I can't get access to the instance vars...

I posted the code here: http://pastebin.mozilla.org/1201689

Does anyone have any ideas?

Really appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 2):

Tasks like these are design for i18n (internationalization).  Have a look at section 3 in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html  This uses a file to store them all, but you can change it based on language. It demonstrates exactly what you are looking for.  Even when you are only using 1 language, this will remove duplicate code for frequently used strings.

The other option is to make a module in your app/lib folder that defines your constants.

```
module FlashNoticeConstants
    MY_COMMONLY_USED_FIRST = "test"
    MY_COMMONLY_USED_SECOND = "test2"
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Gazler. Is there any alternative to the i18n lib, might be a bit overkill for what I am trying to do... ???

Comment: I don't really think it is overkill.  This stores all the strings you want in a file, much like you asked for.  You could do it manually, but your result would end up very similar to the i18n solution.

Comment: OK, I've been looking at the INTL lib and it seems like it will probably do the trick. Thanks for the heads up. I'll look into modules as well, really wanted to do it with just ruby classes.

Comment: Really appreciate the heads up Glazer... IYO avoiding the INTL lib would modules be the best way to get variables from external files back into the main controllers? Thanks :)

Comment: Failing the i18n solution, I'd go for the module approach.

Comment: Thanks, been looking @modules (all puns intended) and they seem way more the way i am trying to go. Thanks for the help :) Stack Overflow rules

Comment: Imo you should be using I18n for this, even if you are using only 1 language. It is the standard way in Rails to store your text, and it allows to edit them easily, outside of your code. And if ever, you can now also easily translate your app. If another developer joins you, she will immediately understand what you are doing if you use I18n.